# How can I make TikZ nodes center on a particular symbol/operator?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, diagrams, nodes

Here is a small example document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dju}{\mathbin{\coprod}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 45mm, y = 30mm]
    \node (gh)   at (0, 1) {$  G  \dju   H $};
    \node (fgh)  at (1, 1) {$f(G) \dju   H $};
    \node (ggh)  at (0, 0) {$  G  \dju g(H)$};
    \node (fggh) at (1, 0) {$f(G) \dju g(H)$};
    \begin{scope}[->]
        \draw (gh.east) -- (fgh.west)
              node [midway, above] {$f \dju \id_H$};
        \draw (gh.south) -- (ggh.north)
              node [midway, left] {$\id_G \dju g$};
        \draw (gh.south east) -- (fggh.north west)
              node [midway, above right] {$f \dju g$};
        \draw (fgh.south) -- (fggh.north)
              node [midway, right] {$\id_{f(G)} \dju g$};
        \draw (ggh.east) -- (fggh.west)
              node [midway, below] {$f \dju \id_{g(H)}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what the document looks like when I compile it:

[image]

This diagram looks fairly reasonable, but perhaps it would look nicer if the vertical and horizontal arrows were centered on the disjoint union symbol (`\coprod`). The diagonal arrow should probably remain as it is, pointing from the bottom-right corner of the right-hand summand of the domain to the top-left corner of the left-hand summand of the codomain. Here is the above picture after I messed around with it in mspaint, to show you what I mean:

[image]

How would you go about making TikZ draw the diagram like this? One way that occurs to me is to take each of the four nodes and make the `\dju` and the two summands into separate nodes, with each summand positioned relative to the `\dju` node. However, it is not obvious that the math-mode spacing of the different symbols can be mimicked if you do this.

Unrelated question: In two places in this diagram, the spacing on the right-hand side of the disjoint union symbol seems wrong. This appears to happen when the math operator `\id` is on the left-hand side and an ordinary letter is on the right. Why does this happen? It does not happen if you change the `\mathbin` in the preamble to `\mathord`, but this also makes all of the spacings bigger. The effect does disappear if the `\mathbin` is removed altogether. I confess I do not remember why I put it there in my main document.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're not using the `tikz-cd` package? It would not solve your problem here, but it would make the code a lot shorter, and I think Harish Kumar's solution would still apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Harish's answer that led me to the line of thinking that took me to this answer. However, I am posting it as a separate answer because it's quite different in the end. Harish, your answer was very competent and gave good results, I just found myself asking whether there was a way to do it without fudging things (for example, where does `shorten <= -3ex` come from in your code? Trial and error?) We need to know precisely how much to shorten arrows by, and this calls for the use of boxes and lengths.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dju}{\mathbin{\coprod}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}

\newlength{\lenA}
\newlength{\lenB}
\newlength{\lenC}
\newlength{\lenD}
\newlength{\lenE}
\newsavebox{\saveboxA}
\newsavebox{\saveboxB}
\newsavebox{\saveboxC}
\newsavebox{\saveboxD}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 55mm, y = 35mm]
    \settowidth{\lenA}{$G$}
    \settowidth{\lenB}{$H$}
    \settowidth{\lenC}{$f(G)$}
    \settowidth{\lenD}{$g(H)$}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\lenE}{max(\lenC, \lenD)}
    \savebox{\saveboxA}[\lenE][r]{$G$}
    \savebox{\saveboxB}[\lenE][r]{$f(G)$}
    \savebox{\saveboxC}[\lenE][l]{$H$}
    \savebox{\saveboxD}[\lenE][l]{$g(H)$}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\lenB}{\lenB - \lenE}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\lenC}{\lenE - \lenC}
    \pgfmathsetlength{\lenD}{\lenD - \lenE}
    \node (gh)   at (0, 1) {$\usebox{\saveboxA} \dju \usebox{\saveboxC}$};
    \node (fgh)  at (1, 1) {$\usebox{\saveboxB} \dju \usebox{\saveboxC}$};
    \node (ggh)  at (0, 0) {$\usebox{\saveboxA} \dju \usebox{\saveboxD}$};
    \node (fggh) at (1, 0) {$\usebox{\saveboxB} \dju \usebox{\saveboxD}$};
    \path (gh.east)         -- ++(\lenB, 0) coordinate (mghfghstart);
    \path (fgh.west)        -- ++(\lenC, 0) coordinate (mghfghend);
    \path (gh.south east)   -- ++(\lenB, 0) coordinate (mghfgghstart);
    \path (fggh.north west) -- ++(\lenC, 0) coordinate (mghfgghend);
    \path (ggh.east)        -- ++(\lenD, 0) coordinate (mgghfgghstart);
    \path (fggh.west)       -- ++(\lenC, 0) coordinate (mgghfgghend);
    \begin{scope}[->, every node/.style = {midway}]
        \draw (mghfghstart)   -- (mghfghend)   node [above]       {$f \dju \id_H$};
        \draw (gh.south)      -- (ggh.north)   node [left]        {$\id_G \dju g$};
        \draw (mghfgghstart)  -- (mghfgghend)  node [above right] {$f \dju g$};
        \draw (fgh.south)     -- (fggh.north)  node [right]       {$\id_{f(G)} \dju g$};
        \draw (mgghfgghstart) -- (mgghfgghend) node [below]       {$f \dju \id_{g(H)}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The mystery of the bad spacing around `\mathbin{\coprod}` remains, but is unrelated to the subject matter of this question. (I tried defining `\dju` to be `\amalg`, but that too had bad spacing in the same situations.) To those people suggesting tikz-cd, I would, but for my current document I do not have *too* many commutative diagrams to draw and I don't feel like I would benefit enormously from adopting a new way of doing things when plain TikZ has enough functionality to do what I want to do.

Comment: Putting the `\id` in a group, as in `${\id_G} \dju g$`, fixes the problem.

Answer (score 8):

## Remarks

I didn't change Harish's solution. I just reimplemented it using `tikz-cd` to show the shortened code.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\dju}{\mathbin{\coprod}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\hphantom{f()}G}
\newcommand{\Ha}{H\hphantom{g()}}
\begin{document}
No additional scaling:

\begin{tikzcd}
    \Ga  \dju \Ha \arrow{dr}{f \dju \id_{g(H)}} \arrow{d}{\id_G \dju g} \arrow{r}{f \dju \id_H} & f(G) \dju \Ha \arrow{d}{\id_{f(G)} \dju g} \\
    \Ga  \dju g(H) \arrow{r}{f \dju \id_{g(H)}}                                                 & f(G) \dju g(H)
\end{tikzcd}

Increased \texttt{row sep} and \texttt{column sep}:

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=huge, column sep=huge]
    \Ga  \dju \Ha \arrow{dr}{f \dju \id_{g(H)}} \arrow{d}{\id_G \dju g} \arrow{r}{f \dju \id_H} & f(G) \dju \Ha \arrow{d}{\id_{f(G)} \dju g} \\
    \Ga  \dju g(H) \arrow{r}{f \dju \id_{g(H)}}                                                 & f(G) \dju g(H)
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

Things can get ugly... We can use `phantom` power.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dju}{\mathbin{\coprod}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\id}{id}
\newcommand{\Ga}{\hphantom{f()}G}
\newcommand{\Ha}{H\hphantom{g()}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x = 45mm, y = 30mm]
    \node (gh)   at (0, 1) {$  \Ga  \dju   \Ha $};
    \node (fgh)  at (1, 1) {$f(G) \dju   \Ha $};
    \node (ggh)  at (0, 0) {$  \Ga  \dju g(H)$};
    \node (fggh) at (1, 0) {$f(G) \dju g(H)$};
    \begin{scope}[->]
        \draw[shorten <= -3ex] (gh.east) -- (fgh.west)
              node [midway, above] {$f \dju \id_H$};
        \draw (gh.south) -- (ggh.north)
              node [midway, left] {$\id_G \dju g$};
        \draw (gh.335) -- (fggh.north west)
              node [midway, above right] {$f \dju g$};
        \draw (fgh.south) -- (fggh.north)
              node [midway, right] {$\id_{f(G)} \dju g$};
        \draw (ggh.east) -- (fggh.west)
              node [midway, below] {$f \dju \id_{g(H)}$};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun with plain TeX's math mode only.

```
\def\dju{\mathbin{\coprod}}
\def\id{\mathop{\rm id}}
\def\Ga{\hphantom{f()}G}
\def\Ha{H\hphantom{g()}}
\def\rar#1{\buildrel {#1} \over {\hbox to 4em{\rightarrowfill}}}
\def\dar#1{\Bigg\downarrow\rlap{$\scriptstyle#1$}}
\def\drar#1{\searrow\raise1ex\rlap{$\scriptstyle#1$}}
$$
\matrix{
  \Ga\dju \Ha           & \rar{f\dju\id_H}       & f(G)\dju \Ha\cr
  \noalign{\vskip2ex}
  \dar{\id_G\dju g} & \drar{f\dju g}         & \dar{\id_{f(G)}\dju g} \cr
  \noalign{\vskip1ex}
  \Ga\dju g(H)        & \rar{f\dju\id_{g(H)}}  & f(G)\dju g(H)\cr
}
$$
\bye
```

> [image]